# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\h_php\addTimes.php on line 19

Tags: php, arrays

With the below code I have a problem where I'm getting the 1st and 2nd row just fine, but the 3rd and next rows only give this error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\h_php\addTimes.php on
>   line 19.

```
<?php
$timearry="";
$timearry=array("1:10","1:40","1:20","0:50");
$i=0;
$day1hours="";
foreach($timearry as $times){
    if($i==0){
        echo $day1hours= $times;
        echo "<br>";
    }else{
        $day2hours = $times;
        $day1=array();
        $day1 = explode(":", $day1hours);
        $day2 = explode(":", $day2hours);
        $totalmins = 0;
        $totalmins += $day1[0] * 60;
        $totalmins += $day1[1];
        $totalmins += $day2[0] * 60;
        $totalmins += $day2[1];
        $hoursTotal = $totalmins / 60;
        $hours=0;
        $hours = explode(".", $hoursTotal);
        $hours= $hours[0];
        $minutes = $totalmins % 60;
        echo $day1hours = "$hours".'Hours '."$minutes".' Mints';
        echo "<br>";
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the line 19 pls

Comment: unable to reproduce error on ur edited code. return 1:10
2Hours 50 Mints
3Hours 20 Mints
3Hours 50 Mints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logic,

Here is the mistake

```
echo $day1hours = "$hours" . 'Hours ' . "$minutes" . ' Mints';
```

This line should be

```
echo $day1hours = $hours . ':'.$minutes;
```

Output:

```
1:10
2:50
4:10
5:0
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/477149)

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, it's just a notice, telling you that on the 19th line of your code you're using an offset that doesn't exist.

Assuming the code you posted is complete, this means this line is not working properly:

```
$totalmins += $day2[1];
```

because `$day2` array doesn't seem to have 2 elements.

Did you check if all the elements from `$timearry` are correctly formatted as "H:m"?